# JAX-RS Response Object displaying Object fields as NULL values

Tags: java, json, web-services, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

First time implementing `JAX-RS Client API` in an application and I am having some small problems when it comes to storing the response data, which is returned as `JSON` as a Java BEAN. Refer to the following code snippets below which demonstrate how I have implemented it thus far.

```
object = client.target(uri).request().post(Entity.entity(requestObject, APPLICATION_JSON), Object.class);
```

Essentially, I would like to store the returned `JSON` response from the web service into my Java BEAN, which in this scenario is named `object`. `requestObject` is obviously the data which I am sending through to the web service, and I can confirm that POST does perform the operation successfully.

After the line of code from the above example I have a simple: `object.toString();` call just to see the values currently stored within this `object`. However, when this executes and printed out to the console, all the `object` fields are printed out as `null`, which I do not understand why. I have annotated my Java BEAN class with the following `@XmlRootElement` above the class, although it still does not work. I do have another object nested as a variable in this Class, would that potentially be the reason why it does not correctly come through?

As an example, this is what my JSON returned object looks like when I invoke the web service through CLI `curl`:

```
"response": {
        "description": "test charge",
        "email": "testing@example.com",
        "ip_address": "192.123.234.546",
        "person": {
            "name": "Matthew",
            "address_line1": "42 Test St",
            "address_line2": "",
            "address_city": "Sydney",
            "address_postcode": "2000",
            "address_state": "WA",
            "address_country": "Australia",
            "primary": null
        }
    }
```

Any reasons why this could be happening?

**UPDATE** [Response Bean Class Below]

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "response")
public class ResponseObject {

    // Instance Variables
    private String description;
    private String email;
    private String ip_address;
    private Person person;
    // Standard Getter and Setter Methods below
```

Person Object which belongs to the `ResponseObject Class`

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Card {

    // Instance Variables
    private String name;
    private String address_line1;
    private String address_line2;
    private String address_city;
    private int address_postcode;
    private States address_state;
    private String address_country;
    private String primary;
    // Standard Getter and Setter Methods below
```

Comment: Can you show us your bean class and how you've annotated the fields? Also, which client API are you using? If it's Jersey, it's [pretty finicky](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.18/json.html#json.jaxb.approach.section) about JAXB/Json conversions.

Comment: @azurefrog, I have updated my question so you can see my Java Beans classes. I am using `JAX-RS` however this just provides me with a set of interface classes which `Jersey` uses, right?

Comment: Please make this problem _"reproducible"_. Show the complete code for the client request. Show the server side resource method.

Comment: @peeskillet Server side source is unavailable as this client is communicating with a test payment gateway.

Comment: Can you show the complete client request code. The reason I'm asking for all this stuff is that I'm trying to reproduce the problem, but I can't. For a couple reason's, 1. I have to create my own client code, which may or may not be different from yours. 2. I have to create my own complete runtime environment (dependencies, jersey version and such) because you have not provided this information. 3. I have to create my own server side method. You could try and reproduce the problem by creating your own server side method, that we can use. Other wise it's hard to say

Comment: @peeskillet yes will update my question shortly. I believe it may have something to do with my marshaling process?

Comment: Hmmm.. I was actually able to reproduce the problem. It's weird, when I read the response as a String, it's fine, but when I read it as a `ResponseObject`, the values _are_ in fact null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I was able to reproduce the problem, and after a bit of testing, I realized that the problem was pretty obvious, if I had looked at it from the right perspective. I was originally looking at it from the view that maybe something was wrong with the provider configuration. But after a simple "Jackson only" test, just using the `ObjectMapper` and trying the read the value, it became clear. The problem is with the json format and the structure of the classes.

Here is the structure

```
{
  "response": {
    "description": "test charge",
     ..
    "person": {
      "name": "Matthew",
      ..
    }
  }
}
```

And here are your classes

```
public class ResponseObject {
    private String description;
    private Person person;
    ...
}
public class Person {
    private String name;
}
```

The problem with this is that the top level object is expecting just a single attribute `response`. But our top level object is `ResponseObject`, which *has* no attribute `response`. With the ignore unknown properties on, the unmarhalling succeeds, because the only attribute is `response`, for which no attribute exists, so nothing gets populated.

A simple (Json/JAXB friendly) fix would be to create a wrapper class, with a `response` attribute of type `ResponseObject`

```
public class ResponseWrapper {
    private ResponseObject response;
}
```

This will allow the unmarshalling to succeed

```
final ResponseWrapper ro = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
            .post(Entity.entity(new ResponseWrapper()
                    , MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE), ResponseWrapper.class);
```

---

## Complete Test

**ResponseObject**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "response")
public class ResponseObject {

    private String description;
    private String email;
    private String ip_address;
    private Person person; 

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getIp_address() {
        return ip_address;
    }

    public void setIp_address(String ip_address) {
        this.ip_address = ip_address;
    }

    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }

    public void setPerson(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ResponseObject{" 
                + "\n    description=" + description 
                + "\n    email=" + email 
                + "\n    ip_address=" + ip_address 
                + "\n    person=" + person 
                + "\n  }";
    }
}
```

**Person**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Person {
     // Instance Variables
    private String name;
    private String address_line1;
    private String address_line2;
    private String address_city;
    private int address_postcode;
    private String address_state;
    private String address_country;
    private String primary;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress_line1() {
        return address_line1;
    }

    public void setAddress_line1(String address_line1) {
        this.address_line1 = address_line1;
    }

    public String getAddress_line2() {
        return address_line2;
    }

    public void setAddress_line2(String address_line2) {
        this.address_line2 = address_line2;
    }

    public String getAddress_city() {
        return address_city;
    }

    public void setAddress_city(String address_city) {
        this.address_city = address_city;
    }

    public int getAddress_postcode() {
        return address_postcode;
    }

    public void setAddress_postcode(int address_postcode) {
        this.address_postcode = address_postcode;
    }

    public String getAddress_state() {
        return address_state;
    }

    public void setAddress_state(String address_state) {
        this.address_state = address_state;
    }

    public String getAddress_country() {
        return address_country;
    }

    public void setAddress_country(String address_country) {
        this.address_country = address_country;
    }

    public String getPrimary() {
        return primary;
    }

    public void setPrimary(String primary) {
        this.primary = primary;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" 
                + "\n      name=" + name 
                + "\n      address_line1=" + address_line1 
                + "\n      address_line2=" + address_line2 
                + "\n      address_city=" + address_city 
                + "\n      address_postcode=" + address_postcode 
                + "\n      address_state=" + address_state 
                + "\n      address_country=" + address_country 
                + "\n      primary=" + primary 
                + "\n    }";
    }
}
```

**ResponseWrapper**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class ResponseWrapper {
    private ResponseObject response;

    public ResponseObject getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public void setResponse(ResponseObject response) {
        this.response = response;
    } 

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ResponseWrapper{" 
                + "\n  response=" + response
                + "\n}";
    } 
}
```

**TestResource**

```
package jersey.stackoverflow.jaxrs;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/test")
public class TestResource {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getResponse(ResponseObject ro) {
        final String json = "{\n"
                + "    \"response\": {\n"
                + "        \"description\": \"test charge\",\n"
                + "        \"email\": \"testing@example.com\",\n"
                + "        \"ip_address\": \"192.123.234.546\",\n"
                + "        \"person\": {\n"
                + "            \"name\": \"Matthew\",\n"
                + "            \"address_line1\": \"42 Test St\",\n"
                + "            \"address_line2\": \"\",\n"
                + "            \"address_city\": \"Sydney\",\n"
                + "            \"address_postcode\": \"2000\",\n"
                + "            \"address_state\": \"WA\",\n"
                + "            \"address_country\": \"Australia\",\n"
                + "            \"primary\": null\n"
                + "        }\n"
                + "    }\n"
                + "}";
        return Response.created(null).entity(json).build();
    }
}
```

**Unit Test: TestTestResource**

```
import jersey.stackoverflow.jaxrs.ResponseWrapper;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ContextResolver;
import org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.json.MoxyJsonConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.TestProperties;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestTestResource extends JerseyTest {

    @Test
    public void testPostReturn() throws Exception {
        final WebTarget target = target("test");
        final ResponseWrapper ro = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                .post(Entity.entity(new ResponseWrapper()
                        , MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE), ResponseWrapper.class);
        System.out.println(ro);

    }

    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        enable(TestProperties.LOG_TRAFFIC);
        enable(TestProperties.DUMP_ENTITY);

        return createApp();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configureClient(ClientConfig config) {
        config.register(createMoxyJsonResolver());
    }

    public static ResourceConfig createApp() {
        // package where resource classes are
        return new ResourceConfig().
                packages("jersey.stackoverflow.jaxrs").
                register(createMoxyJsonResolver());
    }

    public static ContextResolver<MoxyJsonConfig> createMoxyJsonResolver() {
        final MoxyJsonConfig moxyJsonConfig = new MoxyJsonConfig();
        Map<String, String> namespacePrefixMapper = new HashMap<String, String>(1);
        namespacePrefixMapper.put("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "xsi");
        moxyJsonConfig.setNamespacePrefixMapper(namespacePrefixMapper).setNamespaceSeparator(':');
        return moxyJsonConfig.resolver();
    }
}
```

**Dependencies in pom.xml**

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>2.13</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-bundle</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency> 
</dependencies>
```

**Result: Just using toString**

```
ResponseWrapper{
  response=ResponseObject{
    description=test charge
    email=testing@example.com
    ip_address=192.123.234.546
    person=Person{
      name=Matthew
      address_line1=42 Test St
      address_line2=
      address_city=Sydney
      address_postcode=2000
      address_state=WA
      address_country=Australia
      primary=null
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Implementing the `ResponseWrapper` class worked like a charm. Although, I still do not really understand why this is required. Much appreciated for the assistance.

Comment: In binding terms `{ }` is an object (class). When we do this `{ "person: { } }`, it would be a class with a `person` attribute, of which the value is an object. So if _that_ was the JSON we were unmarshalling, then it would be appropriate to unmarshal it to `ResponseObject`. But in your case the JSON has has another level. `{ "response:" { "person" : {} } }`, so there needs to be a class to hold the `response` attribute (whose value is an object)

Comment: Makes ultimate sense now. I fully understand now, appreciate your extensive help.